# Feedback Form jQuery returns no data

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, phpmailer

I have an html page with an ajax query to a php file. This php file is supposed to send a message and then provide a response back to the ajax query. However, no matter what I do I can't get any response out of this ajax call. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<form id="feedback-form" method="post">
<table border="0" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td><h4>Name: </h4></td>
<td><input type="text" id="name"></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><h4>Company: </h4></td>
<td><input type="text" id="company_name"></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><h4>Email: </h4></td>
<td><input type="text" id="email"></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><h4>Feedback Category: </h4></td>
<td>
<select id="category">
<option class="placeholder" selected disabled>Select Category</option>
<option value="website">Site Issue</option>
<option value="content">Content Issue</option>
<option value="suggestion">Content Suggestion</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><h4>Message: </h4>(include as much detail as possible)</td>
<td><textarea id="message" style="resize: none;" rows="5"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><h4>Attachment: </h4>(include any material relevant to your request)</td>
<td><input type="file" id="files" multiple></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="Send"></input></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<span id="feedbackResponse"></span>
```

JS:

```
$('#feedback-form').on('submit', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/RK/sendFeedback.php',
            data: $('#feedback-form').serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
              $('#feedbackResponse').html(response);
        },
            error: function (response) {
              $('#feedbackResponse').html(response);
            }
          });

        });
```

PHP:

```
<?php
require '/RK/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = '******.100';                       // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'email@email.com';                   // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password';               // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS
$mail->setFrom('email@email.com', 'DataMotion Wiki');     //Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->addReplyTo('email@email.com', 'No Reply');  //Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addAddress('email@email.com', 'No Reply');  // Add a recipient
$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'DataMotion Wiki Feedback';
$mail->Body    = '<b>From:</b> '.$_POST['email'].'<br/><b>Category:</b> .$_POST['category'].<br/><b>Message:</b> .$_POST['message']
 echo 'Just before sending';
if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Thank you for your feedback. Your message has been sent';
?>
```

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag:  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Hi, I have added those lines and yes I have checked the console but the page just seems to refresh and the console displays no errors pertaining to this function or its requested resources.

Comment: The pages refreshes?

Comment: Yes it does and appends a '?' to the address. It seems like its trying to do its default "submit" action even though I told it not to

Comment: It sounds like you're not hitting the `preventDefault()` for some reason. Add the post method to your form and clear up the spacing between `function` and `(e)`. Then try it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Jay, I did give that a shot and it has started working. I'm just getting a internal error 500 on the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, your JS code placed above the form. So, in this case you need to wrap it into ready function because the feedback-form doesn't exists at the moment where your JS now. So, your code is trying to handle unexisting element.
Ready function runs everything inside only after the DOM is loaded

So, this can work for you

```
$(function(){
        $('#feedback-form').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'sendFeedback.php',
                data: $('#feedback-form').serialize(),
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#feedbackResponse').html(response);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    $('#feedbackResponse').html(response);
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

Also, add method="POST" to your form, since GET is [default form method](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html)

Comment: Ok that definitely seemed to work. What is interesting though, according to the response I'm getting a internal server 500. On to the next problem

Comment: Why should the OP "try this" @Comodo?

Comment: @JayBlanchard, why not?

Comment: I have tried this function, with no difference. The main difference I can see hear is that you wrapped the entire thing inside of another function.

Comment: I was trying to lead you to make your answer better @Comodo, and answer that would be considered "up votable" by SO standards. What would you want the future visitor to glean from your answer? Saying "try this" is like saying "here is an experiment, but I'm not sure if it will work".